# Dismiss Parent View Controller iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, view, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

Im going to a new view using the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        finishViewController *finished = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"finishViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:finished animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Once the new view is loaded the previous view controller is still functioning behind it. Is there a way I can erase it from memory?

Ive tried:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I thought this would be pretty straight forward. T

Thanks

Comment: did you get the answer eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You're presenting a modal view from the parent view controller.

It sounds like what you really want to do is *push* or segue the finished view controller from the parent view controller.

If you are determined to dismiss / erase the parent view controller, why not first pop the parent view controller and then push/present the finished view controller.

Comment: I have it working with this code 

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondView" sender:self];

and the style set to modal, but the previous view is still running behind it (I can hear it), and when i set the style to push it doesn't work. Any more help?

Comment: can't you turn off the sound (and pause whatever else the parent view controller is doing) when the parent view controller hits the "`viewWillDisappear`" method?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[finished makeKeyAndVisible]` it'll make your new controller the only controller.

Comment: Instead of presentModalViewController

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. If you dismiss the parent you'll dismiss both of them.